# React defaultValue not working axios deliverd dynamic data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

Hello im new in React and im trying to play a little with React but heres one point i dont understand.

at first, fetch with axios data who return my data, the following, then i try to put them into the input fields, value(and is readonly), defaultValue is better, now i have the problem, i see nothing, the value exists when i view with firebug, the strange thing is, when i add a unneed character the input get filled by my wanted but not by default.

The very strange thing is, when i put everything in a Array and does a map function over it i have the value

the json code

```
 {"firma":"hallo","strasse":"musterweg 7","plz":"01662"}
```

the js code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class Testx extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data:[]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    var self = this;

    axios.get('http://localhost/index.php')
      .then(function (response) {
        self.setState({ data: response.data});
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.data.firma}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Testx/>, document.getElementById('hello'));
```

Comment: You try to access a property `firma` within an array instead an object

Comment: The `defaultValue` only works for initial rendering. Use `value` instead.

Comment: ah i see, thahts makes not any sense what i do on this position, thank to u ², i think i can create me now a solution whos fit my plans

Comment: Please don't do stuff like `var self = this`. That's outdated. Try to keep the scope of `this` by either using arrow functions or binding your function in the constructor for example.

Comment: @Nocebo, ah okay, my self was only a solution i cant acced the this in my function and found this solution fast on web and well worked

Comment: Yeah, don't worry. Was just for your information ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to wait until the data comes by showing something loading.**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import axios from 'axios';
class Testx extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    data:{}
  };
}
componentDidMount(){
    var self = this;
        axios.get('http://localhost/index.php')
  .then(function (response) {
    self.setState({ data: response.data});
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

}
  render() {
    const { data }= this.state;
    if(data.firma) {
    return (<div>
              <input type="text" defaultValue={data.firma}/>
       </div>);
    }
    return <div>loading...</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Testx/>, document.getElementById('hello'));
```

Comment: you can upvote and check the tick the answer to help me.

Comment: You won't be able to access `firma` though :P

Comment: @DineshKatwal there you go :)

Comment: @stefanBd please tick the answer.

Comment: @DineshKatwal  i did, its counted but of my less power here its not shown, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Initially, your data state is in Array format. So `this.state.data.firma` doesnt work. Instead make it as empty object `{}`.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
class Testx extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    data: {}
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
        axios.get('http://localhost/index.php')
  .then(function (response) {
    self.setState({ data: response.data});
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

render() {
    return <div>
              <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.data.firma}/>
       </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Testx/>, document.getElementById('hello'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The "code style" is outdated. Try to work with arrow functions which bind your functions, such as `setState`. Or bind your functions once in your constructor like `this.myFunction = myFunction.bind(this)` so you are able to access `this`. I already commented that `this.state.data` is declared as an array. Either change it to be an object or access an object by a specific index.

```
class Testx extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data:{}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => { //Note the arrow function to bind this function
    //Functions like componentDidMount are usually already bound

    axios.get('http://localhost/index.php')
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ data: response.data});
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.data.firma}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If your response is an array instead of an object, then try to access `firma` like this: `this.state.data[index].firma`

Answer (score 0):

thanks all, special for the tips and tricks and how i can do thinks better, my questions is solved, big thanks to all for helping me in under 15 min *happy*

im now also found a way playing with https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html and set my state with

```
 handleChange(event) {

        var tmp = this.state.data;
        tmp[event.target.id] = event.target.value
        this.setState({data: tmp});
  }
```

with modding my render

```
   <input type="text" id="firma" value={this.state.data.firma} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Comment: Just for your information: `setState` is asynchronous. So if you someday wonder why a `console.log()` right after a setState shows old results, you should make use of the callback function of `setState`:
`this.setState({data: tmp}, () => console.log(this.state.data));`

Comment: @stefan please post another question

Comment: Do you have another question to this?

Comment: @Nocebo haha yes, im come from php so this async is very special for me, well currently i dont have any other question and im finish for today(bad when u brings ur work home)